# How do I call char constructor instead of char[] constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

My school project asks me to re-create the std::string class (with less detail). I'm having a small problem that I have two conflicting(?) constructors.

The problem is when I want to create a String from a single character. Instead of calling

```
String(char);
```

it calls

```
String(char[]);
```

How can I specify which constructor I would like called?

**Update**
Wow, now I feel silly. I was calling using char* and not a char so of course it would call the array/pointer version. Thanks for making this painfully obvious to me :)

Comment: Are you using single quotes `'` when creating a String?

Comment: Please form an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: _"How can I specify which constructor I would like called?"_ You use one of the corresponding types being passed as parameter to disambiguate.

Comment: Please post a complete code sample.

Comment: Updated post, problem solved. Mistake on my part :) Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Supposed you have the following

```
class String {
public:
    String(char);
    String(char[]);
};
```

you'll use

```
char charvar = 'X';
String s(charvar);
```

to call the 1st form, and

```
char strvar[] = "XXXX";
String s(strvar);
```

to call the second.

Beyond this your question is too unclear/unspecific, to give a concise answer for what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use single quotes to specify a `char` otherwise it will consider it a `char[]` with a single character (aside from the termination character)

```
'a'    // char
"a"    // char[]
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify, I am calling using a char variable.

Comment: @user1929613 So what's the problem actually? Calling your constructor using a `char var;` should choose your 1st form.

Comment: Updated post, problem solved. Mistake on my part :) Thanks for helping.